# Return different templates from views.py based on number of uploaded files by logged in user

Tags: python, django, templates, django-queryset

Expected Behavior:

I have a django app where users upload 'beats' (mp3 files) and I eventually want to have a free tier and a paid tier. The free tier will be limited in the AMOUNT of 'beats' they are able to upload. Say 3 beats max for free users.

I am trying to run a query in my views that will send the user to a template page requiring them to become a premium member if they exceed the amount of beats allowed to be uploaded. It should check who the logged in user is, get the count of beats uploaded by that user, and if it is less than allowed show the upload template else show the sign up template.

Current Behavior:

Using self.request.user is giving my NameError self is not defined. I was able to get the code to work when hard coding the user's ID into the query. Here is my current code.

```
#beatupload/views.py

class UploadView(ListView):
    model = beat
    template_name = 'uploads.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return beat.objects.filter(producer=self.request.user)

class uploadNew(CreateView): # new
    model = beat
    fields = ['title', 'beat']

    success_url = reverse_lazy('uploads')
    #Check number of beats uploaded by user and if exceeds amount require signup
    #To render sign up template if true and proceed to upload if false
    def get_queryset():
        return beat.objects.filter(producer_id="3")   

    if get_queryset().count() <= 2:
        template_name = 'uploadNew.html'
    else:
        template_name = 'becomeMember.html'
    #END CHECK

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.producer = self.request.user
        return super(uploadNew, self).form_valid(form)
```

```
# beatupload/models.py
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models


class beat(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    beat = models.FileField(upload_to='beats/')
    producer = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

If you see in the above class for the ListView, that is successfully listing only the beats which are uploaded by the logged in user. Trying to adapt that code and get a count doesn't work, because I get a "self" is not defined error. For instance:

```
class uploadNew(CreateView): # new
    model = beat
    fields = ['title', 'beat']

    success_url = reverse_lazy('uploads')
    #Check number of beats uploaded by user and if exceeds amount require signup
    #To render sign up template if true and proceed to upload if false
    def get_queryset(self):
        return beat.objects.filter(producer=self.request.user)   

    if get_queryset(self).count() <= 2: ###ERROR COMES FROM HERE###
        template_name = 'uploadNew.html'
    else:
        template_name = 'becomeMember.html'
    #END CHECK

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.producer = self.request.user
        return super(uploadNew, self).form_valid(form)
```

I get the name error on the if statement portion of the code as noted.

If I indent the if statement to be part of the function like this:

```
class uploadNew(CreateView): # new
    model = beat
    fields = ['title', 'beat']

    success_url = reverse_lazy('uploads')
    #Check number of beats uploaded by user and if exceeds amount require signup
    #To render sign up template if true and proceed to upload if false
    def get_queryset(self):
        return beat.objects.filter(producer=self.request.user)   

        if get_queryset(self).count() <= 2:
            template_name = 'uploadNew.html'
        else:
            template_name = 'becomeMember.html'
        #END CHECK

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.producer = self.request.user
        return super(uploadNew, self).form_valid(form)
```

I do not get the error, but django cannot find the templates.

Additionally, it seems to only work (when hard coding producer's id) if I restart the development server. So if the limit is set to <= 2 which I would expect to allow for 3 uploads, I can continue uploading beats for as long as the development server is running. If I stop the server and start it again, I am then redirected to the template becomeMember.html.

```
\views.py", line 27, in uploadNew
    if get_queryset(self).count() <= 2:
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

That is the name error.

This is the template error:

```
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

    django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\Users\Alex.INACOM-SBY\Documents\code\theBeatStore\agBeatStoreRoot\templates\beatupload\beat_form.html (Source does not exist)

    django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Alex.INACOM-SBY\Documents\code\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\beatupload\beat_form.html (Source does not exist)

    django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Alex.INACOM-SBY\Documents\code\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\beatupload\beat_form.html (Source does not exist)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should override `get_template_names` method, something like this:

```
def get_template_names(self):
    if beat.objects.filter(producer=self.request.user).count() <= 2:
        return ['uploadNew.html',]
    else:
        return ['becomeMember.html',]
```

Comment: I am getting an Exception Value 'NoneType' object has no attirbute 'render'.

Would you like to see the traceback?

Comment: Sorry dude, my mistake, I changed the code to return a list.

Comment: Dang, I was thinking up that tree and tried to do a return instead of what was there but had the syntax just a little wrong. This is working as expected now, Thank you! Will accept your answer. 

I assume that my lack of general python knowledge is causing my troubles with Django. Guess I need to go back to python basics.